# Power adapter output voltage detection

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, dc, lithium-ion, adapter

Not sure if this is right place for this question, but since I don't know where else to ask, I will do it here anyway - if this is wrong exchange, please let me know ...

I have 35 W phone charging adapter, which says it can output 5V/2A or 9V/1.67A. As I understand, with phones this kind of adapters detect whether to output 5V or 9V.

How does this detection work? If I have some simpler device, say [this](https://www.petzl.com/INT/en/Sport/Headlamps/CORE) lithium-ion battery, is it okay to charge it using this adapter, or is there danger of damaging battery because of too high voltage?

Comment: Welcome! Please look up _USB PD handshake_.

Comment: Your battery will be fine: it expects 5V, and no USB charger will provide more then that unless the device explicitly asks for it (that is what the PD handshake which @winny mentioned is for).

Comment: Thank you for your answers.